# Elasticsearch KNN search with keyword terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently trying to build a search where the knn search will be used within the set of results from a terms query. Below is my test query, but I run into an error "malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FEILD_NAME]"

```
GET my-index2/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "should":[
        {"terms":{"t":["hello"]}}
        ]
    },
    "knn": {
      "my_vector2": {
        "vector": [2, 3, 5, 6],
        "k": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "_source":["t"]
}
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

From elasticsearch 8.2, you can directly use filters with _knn_search:

```
GET my-index/_knn_search
{
  "knn": {
    "field": "image_vector",
    "query_vector": [0.3, 0.1, 1.2],
    "k": 5,
    "num_candidates": 50
  },
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "file_type": "svg"
    }
  },
  "_source": ["name"]
}
```

The example is from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/knn-search-api.html.

Comment: What if we need results that don't match with "svg". How can we add negative checks in this query. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is malformed and should be like below, i.e. the `knn` query should be inside the `bool/filter` array so that it works on the same set of data as the one selected by the `terms` query.:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "t": [
              "hello"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "knn": {
            "my_vector2": {
              "vector": [
                2,
                3,
                5,
                6
              ],
              "k": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "t"
  ]
}
```

PS: this only works on the _search endpoint since 8.4

Comment: This won't work as part of ES search API as KNN query is a specialized part of ES query DSL.



{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason": "[13:18] [bool] failed to parse field [filter]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason": "[13:18] [bool] failed to parse field [filter]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "[knn] queries cannot be provided directly, use the [knn] body parameter instead"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: @AadharBhatt it depends on the version, knn search has been merged into the main search API endpoint in 8.4